# Addin outlook - Save mail automatically does not work with standard user

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin

I have an outlook addin in which I update programmatically user properties.

Until now, I executed the addin and outlook with administrator rights. Everything was working good.

I attach the event on a forwarded mail :

```
    void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
    {
        try
        {
            MailItem mail = Inspector.CurrentItem as MailItem;
            if (mail != null)
            {
                ((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)mail).Forward += new ItemEvents_10_ForwardEventHandler(Forward_Event);
        }
        finally
        {
            Marshal.ReleaseComObject(Inspector);
        }
    }
```

Then I update the user properties of the mail and save it.

```
    void Forward_Event(object Forward, ref bool Cancel)
    {
        MailItem mail = Forward as MailItem;
        if (mail != null && OutlookHelper.GetUserProperty(mail) != null)
        {
            OutlookHelper.SetUserProperty(mail, null);
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "Before save forward : " + mail.Saved); // mail.Saved = false
            mail.Save();
            EventLog.WriteEntry("Application", "After save forward : " + mail.Saved); // mail.Saved = true
        }
    }
```

I can see in the logs that the property **Saved** of my mail is set to **True** after the call to the Save() method.

However, since I use a standard user to execute the addin (linked to customer needs), when I close the email, a popup appears asking me to save manually the user properties of the forwarded mail. The problem does not appear with admin rights.

Thanks to everybody for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after some intensive researches, the mail is "read only" and then the call to the **Save()** method does not really save. When I removed the call to the save, the popup disappeared... I do not really understand this behavior, but it works !

Hope this will help some other people.